# Huawei does not accept password to unlock

Tags: factory-reset, huawei

I have a Huawei tablet it was reset  now when i try to sign in with Google it gives me a message shown on the image.

[image]

What can i do? Thanks.

Comment: Bypass this via any box which support your tablet cpu ,
i.e > maricle ,umt,z3x,volkano box etc according to my knowledge you need to bypass FRP.

Answer (score -2):

Please sign in using one of the owner's accounts for this device